# expo/vector-icons stopped working after upgrading to Expo SDK 47

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo, font-awesome

After upgrading from Expo SDK 46 to 47, the expo icons stopped working. There are errors that say "fontFamily 'Font Awesome' is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync".

I tried deleting package-lock.json, node_modules and .expo folder and npm install again, as well as removing the expo cache. I have restarted my computer, but the problem remains.

I also tried adding the fonts using useFonts hook from expo: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/

I have in my babel.config.js the preset 'babel-preset-expo'.

I don't know what else to do. I am thinking that this is an Expo Bug.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to one of my projects.  It may be that you are still using the older version of Xcode. SDK 47 requires Xcode 14.0 or greater. https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-47-a0f6f5c038af